# webpack, почему минимизирует scss и не минимизирует просто css, не понимаю

Tags: javascript, webpack

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

{
   test: /\.css$/i,
   use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,'css-loader'],
 },
{
  test: /\.scss$/i,
  use: [
    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
    'css-loader', 
    'sass-loader'
  ],
 },
plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'css/style.css'
    })
  ]
подключены "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
           "style-loader": "^2.0.0,
           "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.1",
           "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
            "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
```

Comment: а что ты импортируеш в своем js? .css или .scss?

Comment: если импортирую scss, он переводится в css и минимизируется в build, а если импортирую css, то он не минимизируется в build

Comment: решил проблему таким образом  {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'css-loader',
            'sass-loader',
        ],
      },но почему предыдущий вариант не сжимал css, я так и не понял...

Comment: странно но главное решилось